# SPA navigation behavior Not Working on Nextjs 13 app directory when deployed on vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel, next.js13

currently I am working on project build with next 13 using app directory
on **localhost SPA **behavior working fine ( I mean when I navigate from page to another ) page not fully reload.

but after deploy my app on vercel this ** behavior not working** . my app act like a normal website fully load the page
check video below

[Peak - 28 April 2023 - Watch Video](https://www.loom.com/share/ec531564fb2747c69e66448278e0cf4f)

anyone can help!
thanks